# Ext.data.Store getTotalCount() doesn't calculate after load

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

My store doesn't always return the right amount of records when calling `getTotalCount()`. This problem occurs after I `load()` the store. I know that there are records in the store at that point of checking.
I am using ExtJs 4.1.3

```
//this.grid = reference to my grid
var count = this.grid.getStore().getCount(), //50
    total = this.grid.getStore().getTotalCount(); //16000

    this.grid.getStore().load();

    count = this.grid.getStore().getCount(); //50
    total = this.grid.getStore().getTotalCount(); //0
```

**How can I get the number of records that could be loaded into the Store if the Store contained all data?**

---

My store configuration.

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: me.modelName,
                remoteSort: true,
                remoteFilter: true,
                pageSize: 50,
                trailingBufferZone: 25,
                leadingBufferZone: 50,
                buffered: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    actionMethods: { read: 'POST' },
                    api: {
                        read: me.urls.gridUrl
                    },
                    extraParams: Ext.applyIf({ FilterType: 0 }, me.urlParams.gridUrlParams),
                    simpleSortMode: true,
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'data',
                        totalProperty: 'total'
                    }
                },
                autoLoad: true
            })
```

I can confirm that the `total` property is send for all of my requests.

```
{
    "succes": true,
    "data": [
    //50 records
    ],
    "total": 16219,
    "errors": []
}
```

Comment: Please provide the Store config and server data - don't you forget to send "total" value?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure you forgot to send the total prop the second time or there is a bug.

Comment: I've updated my post containing the store configuration. The server data is irrelevant.

Comment: @A1rPun, no. It's not. Server response must contain valid "total" value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Load` is asynchronous. When you call it, the store deletes the total count property, and by the time you reach the two lines after load most chances the server hasn't returned yet to update the property:

```
this.grid.getStore().load();

// Server hasn't returned yet for these two lines.
count = this.grid.getStore().getCount();
total = this.grid.getStore().getTotalCount();
```

You should really write:

```
this.grid.getStore().load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        count = this.getCount();
        total = this.getTotalCount();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works :) Still don't get it why `getCount()` returns the right value.

Comment: I assume it returns the previous value, which isn't being deleted upon load.