# getCount of store returns previous count

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have an app that allows the user to enter search criteria and the results are populated from a store into a table. I am try to display a message if no results are displayed in the table. I load the store in my controller on tap of a button like below:

```
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places').getProxy().setUrl('');
    Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places').load();    

    var count = Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places').getCount();
    console.log(count);
```

With var count i am trying to get the count of the store places but all i seem to get is 0 first time around and then the count of the previous search from there on. Anybody any direction in how i could sort this? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266605/ext-data-store-gettotalcount-doesnt-calculate-after-load) solution but could'nt get it to work

Update:

Console:

```
 museum|art_gallery| History.js:96
 10000 History.js:97
 20 History.js:116
 Results History.js:119
 museum|art_gallery| History.js:96
 10000 History.js:97
 20 History.js:116
 Results History.js:119
 20 History.js:116
 Results History.js:119
 museum|art_gallery| History.js:96
 10000 History.js:97
 20 History.js:116
 Results History.js:119
 20 History.js:116
 Results History.js:119
 20 History.js:116
 Results History.js:119
```

Code Implemented:

```
var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places');
store.getProxy().setUrl('');
 store.on('load', function () {
var count = store.getCount();
console.log(count);

if (count>=1) {
console.log("Results");
 } else  if(count<=0) {
console.log("No Results");
}
});
store.load();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your store is not loaded yet when it executes `getCount();`

Try to do

```
var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places');

store.getProxy().setUrl('');
store.on('load', function () {
  var count = store.getCount();
  console.log(count);
});
store.load();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It works but for some reason everytime i press the tap function of the button it now calls the function the amount of times the button has been pressed. Have a look at the update i have above it shows how i have implemented the code and the results in the console museum|artgallery marks each time i press the button and as you can see the executions increase

Comment: Try to add options to the `on()` method - { single: true }